# Easily, quickly replace MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

We have a process which will regenerate a table from scratch, drop the original table, and move the new table into the original's place. Now this should happen very quickly, but sometimes a website request hits the table after it's been dropped but before the new one is renamed. Apart from coding the website to be more robust when there's a database error, is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RENAME TABLE` syntax allows for atomic, multiple renames. See as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable_new LIKE myschema.mytable;
RENAME TABLE myschema.mytable TO myschema.mytable_old, myschema.mytable_new to myschema.mytable;
DROP TABLE myschema.mytable_old;
```

In the above it is impossible for your code to access the table during the `RENAME` operation, and this it cannot happen that the code "does not find the table". It just blocks until `RENAME` operation completes, and the table is always there.

Also worth noting that unless using Percona Server with "fast DROP TABLE patch", `DROP`ping a table might hold locks on your database (namely the `table cache`) for the duration of the operation. And the operation may take a while since it involves evacuating table pages from InnoDB's cache and deleting the table file(s) from the filesystem.

Waiting for some time (eg a couple hours) after the `RENAME` operation can do good since your old-table's pages are more likely to be flushed out by that time, reducing the overall time from `DROP`ping the table.